# Извлечь нужные столбцы

Tags: mysql

У меня есть запрос:

`(`SELECT * FROM logs WHERE ??? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50`)`

Вопрос такой: Как на месте `"???"` поместить такое условие: столбец `"id"` равен `4` и столбец action равен одному из 3х вариантов: `"a_auth_user"`, `"a_logout_user"`, `"a_auth_nopass"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM logs 
  WHERE 
     id = 4 and 
     action in('a_auth_user', 'a_logout_user', 'a_auth_nopass') 
  ORDER BY id 
  DESC LIMIT 50
```